# Key code value for shift+Up,down,right,left arrows in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, keyboard, key-value

i am working on angular,I need to know the key value of shift+Up arrow,shift+down arrow,shift+right arrow,shift+left arrow. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Angularjs is not the matter here.

It depends of javascript.

```
ArrowUp     0x26 (38)
ArrowDown   0x28 (40)
ArrowLeft   0x25 (37)
ArrowRight  0x27 (39)

ShiftLeft   0x10 (16)
ShiftRight  0x10 (16) (the same)
```

> Here is the list of keyboard keys values : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

To handle combinations, like `shift+arrow`, you need to check each event on body dom object for example, and trigger your action when they are two active.

> There isn't any value for combinations (`shift+arrow` or any). You have to use conditions on both events

Comment: If you are using some keyboard shortcuts, then this little gem might be useful for you http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-hotkeys/

Comment: @ Remi Thanks for your quick reply, i know above key value, but what i need is key value of (shift+Up,Down,Right,Left arrows).